# gcc: put all static/writable variables in the .data section

Tags: gcc, elf

By default gcc will put all writable variables in the `.bss` section if they are zero-initialized, and otherwise in the `.data` section. This can be changed with an attribute:

```
static bool initialized __attribute__(( section(.data) )) = false;
```

Is there a way to apply this attribute to all the static/writable variables in the program (or at least per source file), instead of annotating each variable one-by-one with the attribute? Note that I do need a `.bss` section, but only for `extern` references.

Comment: Also, in gcc with the argument "-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss", you can write the the zero-initialized variables in .data too.

Comment: @sinkmanu that does get me closer, though gcc still puts some things in the `.bss` section, for example a static array such as `static char global_string[0x100]` (the `section` attribute does not even work for this case because it only applies to the pointer variable and not to the backing array). So far my best option is to make a linker script that puts everything where I need it. This is not ideal--I'd rather have everything specified in the source code--but it would apparently require attributes and pragmas that are not available in gcc.